# Powershell start-sleep freeze/block interaction on my winforms

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to enter a 10 second wait in order to execute a command in my script.
The problem is that when I run start-sleep my interface flickers or blocks the window.
I tried to do a special function without using start-sleep but the same thing happens.

First solution (Freeze/Block interaction windows)

```
if ($Timeout -gt 0) {
   Start-Sleep -seconds $Timeout
}
```

Second solution (Freeze/Block interaction windows)

```
if ($Timeout -gt 0) {
  Timeout $Timeout
}

function Timeout($seconds) {
    $doneDT = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($seconds)
    while($doneDT -gt (Get-Date)) {
        $secondsLeft = $doneDT.Subtract((Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
        write-host $secondsLeft
    }
 }
```

How could I do to timeout code execution without freezing my winforms?
 Thank you

Comment: How are you running the command? Does it freeze your UI as well? Are you wanting your UI to remain responsive until the command has ran?

Comment: You will need a background job or a second runspace (multithreading). If you don't have that, the GUI is blocked as long as actions are executed... The question is how complex you background task is and if it needs to represent changes in the gui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to do a Background Job using `Start-Job` (easiest) or Runspace (a little hard to do but efficient) for your task so u do not have to rely on the sleep timer to make sure ur command completed. But that is your prerogative.

However, you can use this neat little trick although not ideal, to counter your non-responsive form problem. Use the below block to introduce the 10s delay.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 50; $i++)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}
```

EDIT: Including suggestions.
Sure you can do this inside WinForms. I have done this before. I just moved onto `Runspaces` later for reasons of efficiency and resources. But for simple purposes, `Start-Job` is the easiest way to go.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    #super lengthy code enclosed in paranthesis to create a scriptblock
    #say takes a large amount of time to complete
}
$myJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock

Do
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
}
While ($myJob.State -ne "Completed")

$myJob | Receive-Job
```

Now you can include contingencies for when the job fails and stuff, but I will let u figure that out.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'd like to use start-job and get-job but I couldn't do it for winforms. Can you suggest how I could do it? Thank you

Comment: @PaoloRossi Check out the new edit. hopefully that would be helpful.